# How to check how many true and how many false items is in Array (SWIFT3)

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement, boolean

I need some help. I want to check how many booleans (`true`,`false`) is in array. How to check this using only if statement.

```
var voteArray: Bool = [true,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true]
```

and then, add `[true]` to other array, and `[false]` to other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` your array for that.

```
var voteArray = [true,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true]
let trueArray = voteArray.filter { $0 }
let falseArray = voteArray.filter { !$0 }
//If you want count also then simply access count property of both trueArray and falseArray
```

**Edit:** As in comment you have mentioned that you want to handle this with `for loop`, I don't know why you want like this but you have asked so you can go like this way.

```
var voteArray = [true,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true]
var trueArray = [Bool]()
var falseArray = [Bool]()
for item in voteArray {
    if item {
        trueArray.append(item)
    }
    else {
        falseArray.append(item)
    }
}

//Or you can go with individual for loop for both true and false

//For true
for item in voteArray where item {
    trueArray.append(item)
} 

//For false
for item in voteArray where !item {
    falseArray.append(item)
}
```

Comment: I know I found this method on stack, but I try to make this using if statement, did You know how to do this?

Comment: @Marcin Can you explain a bit more what you want, what do you mean by using if edit your question with more detail.

Comment: I want to create a for…in loop that loops over one of the vote collections and checks the value of each vote. If the vote is true, the loop should add one vote to the yes variable. If it's false, it should add one vote to the no variable.

Comment: @Marcin You mean you want to append object one by one using for loop and what is the necessary of that?

Comment: Yes, can You help with this?

Comment: @Marcin I will But can you please tell me why you want like that are you want to add some other object from array on the basis of this voteArray?

Comment: Yes :) This is my first steps with Swift and this is my challenge for today :D

Comment: @Marcin Check the edited answer for that.

Comment: @Marcin Reply here that this is what you are looking here.

Comment: Cool, thank You :)

Comment: @Marcin Welcome mate :)